# ToggleClass('active') on Angular and Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, button, click

Anyone knows how can I do something like this with Angular?

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('button').toggleClass('active');
  $('.title').toggleClass('active');
  $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `ngClass` https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this(`[class.className]="conditionThatResolvesToABoolean"`, or `[ngClass]`) for doing this:

```
<div [class.active]="classApplied">
  Here's some text
  <button (click)="toggleClass()">Toggle Class</button>
</div>
```

And in your Template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  classApplied = false;

  toggleClass() {
    this.classApplied = !this.classApplied;
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igl2xq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: How about if I have to toggle the class on multiple elements.
classApplied toggles them on every instance simultaneously...

Comment: If your instances are a part of a list, each object in that list backing up an instance could additionally have a property that determines whether the class should be applied or not. And you could use the index of the item in the list to only set this property for the item present at that index. Hope that makes sense. If not, I'd urge you to create a new question thread and I'd be happy to answer in there. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case i have added Toggle class like that:

Component-HTML

```
<button (click)="darkMode()">Dark Mode</button>
```

Component-TS

```
 darkMode() {
    const themeClass = document.querySelector('body');
    themeClass?.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
 }
```

And its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Typescript code to solve this problem

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
    })
    export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    
      is_active = "";
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      toggleNav(){
        if(this.is_active){
          this.is_active = "";
        }
        else{
          this.is_active = "is-active";
        }
      }
    
    }
```

This is my way to do it
now we can use is_active property in the html code

```
<div class="navbar-burger {{is_active}}" role="button" (click)="toggleNav()" data-target="navbarExampleTransparentExample">
```

Comment: fo something like this u can use public isActive = false; remove toggleNav func, and in html: [class.is-active]="isActive" (click)="isActive = !isActive"